# Could Atlas Ad Astra mean "A collection of maps to the stars"?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

If *Ad Astra* means to the stars, and *Atlas* means a collection of maps, would *Atlas Ad Astra* convey the meaning that a collection of map?

If not, what is the grammatical way of saying it?

Comment: Tycho Brahe called his book Planispharium; but that is late Latin, and possibly too constricted.

Answer (score 1):

The word *Atlas* is originally the name of [the titan who ended up holding up the sky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlas_(mythology)).
The [use in cartography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlas) originates from Mercator's 1595 book *Atlas Sive Cosmographicae Meditationes de Fabrica Mundi et Fabricati Figura*.
Atlases existed before that but they were called something else.

It is possible to use the word *Atlas* for a collection of maps in Latin, but I would advise against it.
In the context of Latin the word is mainly understood to refer to the titan.
You should use another word for a map, but that is a little tricky, too.

There are many possible words; at least *mappa*, *charta*, and *tabula* come to mind.
They actually all refer to the underlying medium (piece of cloth, paper, tablet) rather than the content of a map.
Therefore they are all prone to misunderstanding.

To move from a word for "map", like *charta*, to "atlas", you can derive a word like *chartarium*.
This word means an archive and therefore clarification is needed — recall that *charta* is closer to "paper" than "map".
My best suggestion for "atlas" is ***chartarium geographicum***.

*Ad astra* is indeed "to the stars".
It is not "of the stars", so you are getting maps for a journey to the stars, not a map of the stars.
Whether this is a good choice of words depends on context.

Therefore a collection of maps to the stars could be ***chartarium geographicum ad astra***.
This might feel clumsy, but if you go any simpler, it no longer unambiguously means what you want to it mean.
(Unless I'm missing something, of course!)
Depending on context, there might be something simpler that conveys the right idea.

Comment: Joonas llmavirta: Does "ad astra" imply the making of a journey, to the stars?

Comment: @tony Yes, it is "to the stars", not "of the stars" or similar. It does indeed imply a journey, and I'll update the answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 1):

You're not the first person to have this problem. Here are some earlier names for a star atlas.

1588  Tycho Brahe ***Planispharium***
 ...[1602], Tycho Brahe ***De Mundi Aetherei Liber***
1603 Johann Bayer ***Uranometria***
1690 Hevelius – ***Uranographia***
1729 John Flamsteed  ***Atlas Coelestis***,
1950 Skalnate Pleso ***Atlas Coeli***

Answer (score 0):

Instead of *atlas*, I recommend the word *itinerarium*. In later Latin, it became a common word to describe the course of a journey. For instance, St. Bonaventure's *Itinerarium Mentis in Deum* means *The Soul's Journey to God*, and the book contains instructions for making the journey. In the early modern period, travelers would write itineraries of their journeys, listing all the stops they made, and often the distances between them. This seems the most appropriate to me, since *ad astra* implies that you're giving someone directions, not just describing an area.

But you could also use the term *tabulae* or even *mappae*, which are common terms for "maps."